# Is a better solution like a single set operation possible

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I can't think of a single T-SQL operation through the following problem can be  solved. I can think only of record by record operation to solve the problem.

The problem is as follows:

1. For each village a number of shops are assigned ( from 1 to n).
2. Same shop can serve more than one village.
3. Each shop has different maximum capacity (that is given in a table)
4. Need to assign all members of  a family (based on family id) to same shop in such a way that `'nearly' equal families are assigned to each FPS. As the number of families may not be equally divisible FPS number a few shops may get one additional Family. While assigning last family if the FPS max capacity exceeds by a few member that is acceptable. This however would not happen if last family has just one member.
5. Some families may remain unassigned if FPS max capacity exceeds for all FPS assigned to that village.

Available tables

- `Population`: Uniqid, Familyid, name, shopcode, villagecode
- `Village`: VillageId
- `Shop`: ShopId, Name, MaxCapacity
- `VillageShopMap`: VillageId, ShopId

My solution is as follows

- Take each village

  - Get one Family for that village
  - Get a shop with minimum number of person allotted for that village , whose current capacity < max Capacity
  - Continue until that population from that village is exhausted, or Shop MaxCapacity is reached (in that case some people remain unassigned to shops, that is acceptable)
  - Loop

My solution is extremely slow. Looking for a better solution.

Thanks

Comment: You either miss person or family table - currently family meber count can't be found anywhere. Then - this is not strictly SQL question; you just need to invent better algorithm, optionally able to work with data sets.

Comment: It's not clear what you are optimizing for. Are you trying to get as close to maximum capacity in each shop? Or to have as many villages 100% served as possible? Or...? In general, this looks like a knapsack problem, and I'm not sure if there's any simplification. How are you going to "grade" the solutions? How close you need to get to the optimal solution?

Comment: @Arvo - yes there was a mistake on my part on describing the village.

Comment: @Lusan - What I am trying to optimize 1. speed and 2. equal distribution within the maxcapacity. My solution is extremly slow.

Comment: What do you mean by equal distribution? The same % of capacity used in each of the stores (the obvious solution would be to not assign any families :P)? Or the same ratio of family:store capacity in each village? Speed... probably isn't going to be very good - this kind of problem is quite tricky, even if you used a more reasonable language than SQL for the task.

Comment: @Luaan sorry I misspelled your name in my previous comment. Equal distribution is actually near equal distribution of families. As families have unequal members, actual number distribution would not be exactly same and that is acceptable.

Comment: That didn't help me much, sorry :D Do you mean that you want each shop to have the same amount of families, or family members? That would mean that you could ignore the maximum capacity of a shop, and instead only work with the *smallest* shop available. Those are the kind of simplifications that can make knapsack bearable...

Comment: Every shop should have nearly same amount of families. ('nearly'because there will be situations where number of familes can not be equally divided by the number of  FPS assigned to that village). Yes, incase while assigning the last fmaily to a shop maxcapcity is exceeded  by a small number (number of family members) that is acceptable (this would not happen only for single member family).

Comment: Aggregate families over possible shops and assign biggest possible families to biggest free capacity shops - this can be done in set-based manner. Repeat until no more assignments can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Not much but could use this to fill a shop in one pass
In this case 20 is the shop capacity
The top 20 is just to not evaluate more than needed - a family will have at least one

This could leave some shops empty
You could scale capacity to a fraction of the actual capacity

```
with famA as 
( select top 20 sParID as ID, count(*) as famSize
    from docSVsys 
   group by sParID 
)
, fam as
( select famA.*, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ID) as rn 
    from famA
)
, famCum as
( select fam.ID, famSize, fam.rn,   
         (select sum(f.famSize) from fam f where f.rn <= fam.rn) as cum 
    from fam  
)   
select famCum.* 
  from famCum 
 where famCum.rn <= (select max(f.rn) from famCum f where f.cum <= 20) + 1 
 order by famCum.rn
```

Repeating shopcode and village code in Population is not 3NF
Should have a Family table and I would denormalize and put a famsize in the table so you are not calculating size over and over.

Or assume you have the above Family table and a ShopView with CurCapacity
Can assign a one family to all open shops in one pass

```
with ShopOne as 
(  select ShopId, min(VillageID) as VillageID
     from ShopView 
    where CurCapacity < Max Capacity 
)
, FamilyRn as 
(  select Family.*, row_number (over VillageID order by ID) as rn 
     from Family where ShopID is null 
)
select Family.*, ShopOne.*  
  from ShopOne 
  join FamilyRn 
    on ShopOne.VillageID = Famility.VillageID  
   and FamilyRn = 1
```